# Signature image on line with text beneath

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I try to make a signature inside a latex template with a hand written signature image from a png. I like to place it on a line with the name as text beneath. I've tried to make it with a table, but i failed to place it directly on the line. I hope someone can help me here.

[image]

Comment: Does the signature image have a transparent background? Otherwise it becomes hard to  put the line behind it. Wheneven I've made something like this, I drop the line, and just place the `My Name` at an appropriate place beneath the image, but still on top of it. The method in Salims answer will do this easily.

Answer (score 2):

With tikz, simply change the vertical location of the signature image with `yshift` key

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick](0,0)--(5,0)node[midway,yshift=1.2cm](c){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[yshift=-3mm] at (c.south) {\bfseries My Name};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
% on preamble
\def\sign{\includegraphics[scale=.8]{fig-here}\\[-4ex]} % set up the value
\def\myname{Euclides}
\def\LocalData{City, \today}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}\LocalData\par\bigskip 
   \begin{minipage}{6cm}\centering
   \sign\hrulefill\\\myname
   \end{minipage} 
   \end{flushright} 
\end{document}
```